# Finding top-k most frequent items in a stream, Does a space efficent implementation exist in c?

Tags: c, word-frequency

lets say we have a stream of data being supplied (maybe words) and we want to know what the top k most frequent items are. For example for:

```
foo bar foobar foo bar
```

the top 2 most frequent words are `foo` and `bar`.

This can easily be done with a hashmap however that would need as much space as we have words. Does a space (and time) efficient implementation of such an algorithm exists in C (an approximation of the most frequent terms is fine).

I know of a Java implementation at: https://github.com/addthis/stream-lib A c++ implementation exists at http://hadjieleftheriou.com/frequent-items/index.html however I can not seem to find a C implementation.

Comment: A hash table with word count field would be the basic implementation. 
 Typically, for a good data structure for a dictionary you'd want to store the words in a trie for efficient searching as the words stream in.

Comment: Maintaining a trie is probably the best solution. And it is as efficient in time as a hashtable, but occupies less space.

Comment: You will certainly find count-min sketch implementations for C if you look around, and the various top-k estimation algorithms are documented well enough that it is not too challenging to write a specific implementation for your problem domain. If you run into trouble with your implementation,of feel free to return with a specific question. But SO discourages questions of the form "please recommend me a lbrary". See [ask].

Comment: You may want to look at a [Ternary Search Tree](https://github.com/drankinatty/ternary_st) which is far more space efficient than a trie, and each terminal word node can contain a `count` capturing the frequency of each word. For your purposes it appears you can ignore the word-removal portion of the code.

Comment: I ended up writing my own, I used androids's hashmap implementation (as it was very simple) and then wrote the actual top-k algorithm as described in  "Efficient Computation of Frequent and Top-k Elements in Data Streams" by "Ahmed Metwally" et al.  I guess I can delete this question if anyone feels strongly about it. Thanks for the offerings of help :)